# AFNetworking AFHTTPClient Different content types for success and Fail

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am trying to access a web service, via an AFHTTPClient subclass, that has a complication

If the request succeeds, the content is returned as JSON. If it fails for some reason, the error from the server is returned formatted as XML.

At the moment, the only way I figure I can deal with this is the not attempt to use the specific XML/JSON RequestOperations, and purely treat everything as a plain HTTP request, and then attempt to parse it manually myself, depending upon what the response looks like.

Sadly, I have no control over the web service, or I'd make sure it was *all* JSON.

Does anybody have any better suggestions for handling this?

[EDIT]

I guess one way of making it slightly cleaner, would be creating a new subclass of AFHTTPRequestOperation, that handled the detection of content type internally, and then passed back either parsed JSON or a GDataXML object depending upon what was returned from the server.

Thanks

Comment: This is similar to several web services I have used, JSON on success and plain text on fail. The best you can do is either throw an error on a different content type to JSON or try and parse the response for specific errors.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the cleanest or most optimal solution, but you could do a check with an existing JSON library that the response is in fact valid JSON. If it is, proceed as usual; if it isn't, treat it with your hand-carved parsing solution.

Comment: Thanks. I considered that approach, but didn't like the idea of overhead of attempting to parse it just to get a 'fail' back. I guess the parsing probably has an early out if it detects non-JSON, so probably shouldn't be too inefficient.